# How can I hide & Show a div element in a Component from 2 other components which don't have child parent relation?

Tags: angular

> In angular 2 app I have 3 different components Comp_A ,Comp_B and
>   Comp_C. Comp_C has no parent child or sibling relation with other 2
>   components. Comp_B is the child of Comp_A. I am passing a button click
>   event with EventEmitter  through a sharedService to hide/show div
>   block in Comp_C. in my code from Comp_A i can hide the div block in
>   Comp_C. But unable to show the same div again from Comp_B with the
>   help of same event emitter and shared service.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Use a shared service with an observable (`BehaviorSubject`) to notify about changes for the receiver to make. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service (even when the chapter name has parent-child in its name this works across your whole application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    **Comp_C**
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ComponentA} from 'src/ComponentA';
import {SharedService} from 'src/shared.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './main-page.component.html',
    providers : [SharedService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  viewList : Boolean;

  constructor(ss: SharedService) {
      this.viewList = false;
      this.ss = ss;
    }



    ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.ss.getEmittedValue()
      .subscribe(item => this.viewList=item);
  }

}

**main-page.component.html**

<div>
   <div *ngIf = " viewList == false">
       <mydata-list-component> </mydata-list-component>
   </div>
</dive>


----------


**Comp_A**

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {SharedService} from 'src/shared.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',

    templateUrl: './menu-bar.component.html',

})

export class MainComponent {

    ss;

    constructor(ss: SharedService) {
      this.ss = ss;
    }

    hideListView() {
      this.ss.hide();
    }

}



**menu-bar.component.html.html**

<div>
   <button (click)="hideListView()">hideListView</button>
</dive>


----------

**Comp_B**

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {SharedService} from 'src/shared.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',

    templateUrl: './menu-bar-sec-page.component.html',

})

export class MainComponent {

    ss;
    constructor(ss: SharedService) {
      this.ss = ss;
    }

    show ListView() {
      this.ss.show();
    }
}



**menu-bar.component.html.html**

<div>
   <button (click)="showListView()">hideListView</button>
</dive>


----------

**SharedService**


import {Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'


@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  @Output() fire: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   constructor() {
     console.log('shared service started');
   }

   show() {
    console.log('show started'); 
     this.fire.emit(false);
   }

   hide() {
    console.log('hide started'); 
     this.fire.emit(true);
   }

   getEmittedValue() {
     return this.fire;
   }

}
```

Comment: code should be posted to question and not as answer

Comment: @Aravind I think this is the answer. It works fine for me. If you feel something wrong let me know it.